# Jquery to update dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to use jQuery to change following dropdown for example

```
<select id="select1">
        <option value="free">Free</option>
        <option value="basic">Basic</option>
 </select>
```

to

```
 <select id="select1">
        <option optionId="0" value="free">Free</option>
        <option optionId="1" value="basic">Basic</option>
 </select>
```

The optionIds value will depend on the number of options. 
I am not able to hard code  dropdown, it needs to be jquery. 
The number of options is generated by MVC DropdownListFor()

Not sure but something like, but not sure how to set unique values:

```
$(.select1 options).attr("optionId")
```

Comment: Why do you want that optionId - what is the intention of that value?

Comment: automation testing

Comment: You can get the option index without adding a custom attribute.  Is there a reason it's named optionId rather than something more standard like data-id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery (or plain JavaScript) you can create a function that accepts a select ID and adds the attributes to the option elements. It would also be easy to modify the code to apply the attribute to all selects on the page.

Note that jQuery attr() (setAttribute) converts names to lower case. So optionId becomes optionid.  Would be better to use a data attribute for this like data-id, which would be more standard.

```
function setOptions(id) {
  $("#" + id + " option").each((index, option) => {
    $(option).attr("optionId", index);
  });
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
function setOptions(id) {
  $("#" + id + " option").each((index, option) => {
    $(option).attr("optionId", index);
  });
  
  stdout.innerHTML += $("#" + id).html(); // test
}


setOptions("select1");
setOptions("select2");
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="free">Free</option>
  <option value="basic">Basic</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="free">Free</option>
  <option value="basic">Basic</option>
  <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
</select>

<br/>
HTML:
<textarea id="stdout" style="width:100%;height:8em;"></textarea>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```